# Show all child categories associated to post ID within loop

Tags: loop, categories, children

I'm looping through all posts and I'm trying to output the category nicename related to each post. So if there are categories A,B and C with post X only associated with categories A and C then I only want to output category A and C's nicename.

Here's the loop:

```
<?php $subs = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'case-study' ));
      if( $subs->have_posts() ) : while( $subs->have_posts() ) : $subs->the_post(); ?>

      <?php the_title(); ?>

      <p>Associated Child Categories</p>
      //Show nicenames of each child category associated to each post
      <?php $category = get_categories($post->ID);
            foreach(($category) as $cats) { echo $category->category_nicename; }?>

<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [`get_the_categories()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_category)

> Returns an array of objects, one object for each category assigned to the post. This tag may be used outside The Loop by passing a post id as the parameter.

```
$categories = get_the_categories();
var_dump( $categories );
```